# mc 1.7.10 Forge ошибка "java.lang.ClassCastException" в runtime

Tags: java

Помогите пожалуйста, я новичок в "ява". Взял за основу buildcraft 7.1, решив сделать свой автоверстак, но почему то когда запускаю с Tile'ом buildсraft'а то всё работает и GUI открывается, но если копирую из исходников его Tile и подключаю то во время выполнения возникает ошибка приведения к типу, хот я я же по сути то ничего не менял, а лишь использовал немного иначе, ведь возвращается TileEntity а он "родитель" TileBuildCraft, я думал родительский класс должен приводиться к дочернему без вопросов "на ура"  почему так происходит? Уже всё перепробывал, ничего не помогает...

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: buildcraft.factory.TileAutoWorkbench cannot be cast to com.silvercraft.tile_entity.TileAutoWorkbench
at com.silvercraft.handler.SCGuiHandler.getServerGuiElement(SCGuiHandler.java:36) ~[SCGuiHandler.class:?]
```

TileBuildCraft: http://paste.ubuntu.com/23203777/

TileAutoWorkbench: http://paste.ubuntu.com/23203781/

IGuiHandler: http://paste.ubuntu.com/23203795/

ContainerAutoWorkbench: http://paste.ubuntu.com/23203804/

Лог: http://paste.ubuntu.com/23203829/

Answer (score 1):

> родительский класс должен приводиться к дочернему без вопросов "на ура"

Нет. Дочерний класс всегда можно привести к родительскому, но не наоборот.
Пример:

```
    class A{
        void funcA(){
            //do smth A
        }
    }
    class B extends A{
        void funcB(){
            //do smth B
        }
    }
class Main{
    public static void main(String[] args){
        A aa = new A();
        A ab = new B();
        B bb = new B();
        aa.funcA(); // - выполнится
        bb.funcB(); // - тоже выполнится
        ab.funcB(); // - выдаст ошибку, потому что в классе А не
                    //задекларирован метод funcB();
    }
}
```

Comment: Да перепутал когда ночью писал, дочерний к родительскому а не наоборот ибо сущности родительского в дочерний включены, а в родительский дочернего далеко не факт,  

TileAutoWorkbench дочерний от TileBuildCraft  и тот наследуется от TileEntity соответственно, у меня как раз запускается и ошибка на этапе работы а не проверки кода, в том и сложность. Но всё равно спасибо за ответ.